# What is the longest password for SSH?

Tags: ssh, password

What is the longest (how much characters) for SSH password?

I like strong and long password but dont know the character limit.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use RSA instead of an incredibly long password that you will have to write down to remember?

Comment: Use a key instead and disable logins without a key if you really want it to be secure.

Comment: It actually makes sense to have a long password if you use keys -- it makes the keys the *easiest* way in, not the *hardest*. Make a crazy-long password, write it down, lock it up, and only use it in emergencies. Writing down your passwords is a Good Thing if you keep it safe. People are better at safeguarding *things* as opposed to *ideas*.

Comment: tylerl, credits to Bruce Schneier for your last sentence :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no fixed maximum length. Your password is not stored, a "salted hash" of your password is stored, usually in the /etc/shadow file, which is always of a particular length. Even if your password is 50+ characters, the hashed representation of the password will be much smaller.

By all means use strong passwords, but passwords are meant to be easy to use and memorable - if you make it too long, you might end up needing to write it down, which would probably be a bigger security concern than a shorter password.

Comment: There _may_ be a limit in the SSH client or server, or in the protocol itself. (Goblin was asking specifically about a SSH password.)

Comment: "SSH password" doesn't really mean much. If the question is about "passwords protecting ssh private keys", there's still no fixed maximum length on openssh...

Comment: "Even if your password is 50+ characters, the hashed representation of the password will be much smaller." I checked out my /etc/shadow file and the hashed password for my user is way more than 50 characters at 118. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). This suggests to me that an extremely long password would still be beneficial.

Comment: A password doesn't need to be short to be easy to remember. Which is why I ended up googling "linux maximum password length" and ended up here. I have several server, MacOS, and WSL passwords that are too weak because storing them in my password manager isn't practical. But diceware passwords are strong and easy to remember. They just don't work when there's a password size limit.

Answer (score 3):

Several things are being conflated here both in the question and in the answers. Let's sort some out.

SSH does not impose any limit on password length. In fact SSH doesn't ever know anything about your password. It has several authentication modes, including key (e.g. RSA, mentioned elsewhere) and *keyboard-interactive*, which is what lets you use a password. In keyboard-interactive mode, you're just passing a password to whatever is on the back end.

Typically for a Unix-like server, that back end is Pluggable Authentication Modules, or PAM. It isn't always, but exceptions are unusual.

PAM, in turn, supports multiple back ends for validating your password. The one people have been discussing — `/etc/shadow` — is part of the `pam_unix` backend. Pam_unix checks the authentication token you entered in keyboard-interactive mode against your hashed password in the /etc/shadow file.  Strictly speaking there is no limit on password length here either, but there are limits on how long a password is meaningful. It depends on the hash being used.

As was said, conventional Unix DES encryption only pays attention to 8 letters of your password (56 bits). You can use a longer password, but everything beyond the first 8 characters is thrown away. (I've never heard that, as someone else said, MD5 hashing only uses 8 characters, and I don't think it's true. If so that constraint is implemented somewhere in the PAM tooling, not in the hash itself.)

That said, the bit length of the hash determines the possible collision space between two passwords, and therefore determines how long a password is meaningfully more secure.  MD5 is 128 bits; SHA1 is 160; SHA256 is 256, etc.

So for pam_unix:

1. There is no physical limit on password length.
2. ... although some tools that consume your password might have limited buffer sizes and truncate it or crash.
3. Only DES limits the useful length of your password, to 8 7-bit ASCII symbols.
4. Anything else allows unlimited password length.

But wait! Pam_unix isn't the only backend!

Many servers, especially in enterprise environments, use LDAP or Active Directory backends for authentication. These could, in principle, have their own password length limitations — but that's not an SSH property, that's a directory service property. You'd need to ask in a community for those services. But, in practical terms, I don't expect you'd run into any password length limits with any common LDAP or AD deployment, either. If you do, it's almost certainly a weak or compromised infrastructure.

So go wild with your password-typing self — a minimum of 16 characters is recommended, although I've used as many as 75 depending on what I'm protecting
 — and then set up RSA authentication so you don't have to type so much.

Answer (score 1):

If the password is stored as DES or MD5 then only the first 8 characters are significant. SHA passwords have no such limit. See the `crypt(3)` man page for details.

Comment: Not really. The password is hashed to a 8-byte string by MD5, as you say, but there are limit also for SHA. SHA1 is 20 bytes (160 bits), SHA 256 is... wanna guess?

Comment: @Dan: That's the size of the resulting hash, not which characters of the password are relevant.

Comment: You are right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253 -- SSH is a secure protocol for communicating with a remote terminal, and doesn't use a password (it uses a cryptographic key negotiation).
That said once you are connected to the remote terminal, you will usually see an "message of the day"(MOTD) and be asked for login credentials, the rules of which are determined by the OS of the remote terminal. (Overflowing the character buffer of the name or password field is a recurring security flaw) popular limits are 8, 32, and 255 characters in length.

Comment: *telnet* just connects like plain old terminal, especially a switched one like a dialup modem (if you remember those), and relays the normal login prompt etc (canonically /etc/login on Unix).
*SSH* however handles password or other authentication *in the protocol*, limited both by the standardized protocol and the options enabled by both server and client. Decrement your rfc to 4252 and see especially 5.4 and 8. Oh, and SSH can be used as a general secure transport for many things, not only a remote terminal/shell, although that's a very important use.

Comment: I'm sorry, have you actually used SSH? It only uses cryptographic key negotiation if you take the time to set it up.